# Count Number and Track IP Address of Software Installation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We have developed a windows application. To distribute it, we put it on different software distributor website and My organization wants me to track IP, Location and count number of downloads of the software. I put some script to track this on our main product website but as I told that we are distributing this software through different vendors well so my question is how to track these ("Software which is downloaded by third party website") downloads. Is there any way to put some tracking code inside the software (in xml or any other format). The application is developed in c# on .Net framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a code to do this in your C# application but you have to ask the users if they wants to participate in this feedback feature. you will need a server to hold the logs or use a ready made analytics if you use .net https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3